# How do you use the Datamuse API to get words, and then unpack the JSON response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to js programming and attempting to use Datamuse to get some words to use in a hangman program. I have been searching for an example on how to call Datamuse in js but haven't really been able to find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is a rudimentary example using MVC .NET that consumes Datamuse API

//Controller Class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DictMVC.Models;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace DictMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var client = new HttpClient();

            string word = "whittle";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.datamuse.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("words?ml="+word).Result;

            List<WordDefViewModel> words = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<WordDefViewModel>>().Result;

            ViewData["word"] = word.ToUpper();

            return View(words);
        }
}
}

// View Model Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DictMVC.Models
{
    public class WordDefViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Meaning")]
        public string Word { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Parts of Speech")]
        public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    }
}

// Index View
@model IEnumerable<DictMVC.Models.WordDefViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DICTIONARY";
}

<h2>Word Of The Day: @ViewData["word"]</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Word)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tags)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Word)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
                {
                    @(tag + " ")
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```